# Do I need to show progress when working with a database?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar, android-database

I get data for 50 items, the request is very fast and the progress does not even have time to appear on the screen. During the scroll, when there are 6 elements left, the next 50 are loaded to the end and progress also does not have time to appear on the screen. Is there any reason why I should still show progress?

Comment: This is related to UX and will mostly be based on opinion, probably not something we can provide an answer for, better to ask on a UX community or hire a professional

Comment: Progress visibility may depend on internet connection. You can connect to the poor connection you will see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i would implement it, because, if somebody with slow connection gets connected, or somehow the query needs more time to process, the user will be at least prompted something.

I think it's a must for UX.

Comment: That depends if the database is local or remote. If local then it's unlikely that queries will take long enough for the user to notice

Comment: as far as i know, some studies says that too fast loading time, on certain actions ( for example updating bank data, or private information ) don't make the user feel "safe". I agree with your comment by the way! It probably became an habit to me!